# Can a SOAP client in Java handle WCF message credential

Tags: java, .net

Need to communicate from a Java platform with a SOAP server implemented in .NET with [transport security and message credentials.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-transport-security-and-message-credentials)

A working .net client has the following setups to talk to the server successfully:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.localMachine);
store.Open(...to load the cert..);
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
...setting the proxy here ...
EndpointAddress endpoint = new Address(the end point);
ClientGenertedFromWSDL client = new ClientGenertedFromWSDL(binding, endpoint);

... setting other stuffs...

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(cert suject name, store.Location, StoreName.My);

...client does something...
```

I have tried using axis1 that comes with eclipse to generate client code, but I don't see there are obvious methods (within xxxLocator where xxx is the service specified in the WSDL, or anywhere related) to handle things similar to WCF message security.

I seem to have successfully set transport level security by doing like

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", certFilePath);
...
```

and I can see client/server ssl hand shaking in the debug log, yet it gets 400 Bad Request back. BTW, I can capture SOAP request and response from the binding (from xxxLocator), and the request sent is exactly the same as the one the .net client sent.

I know there are many ways to generate Java stub/code from a WSDL, for instance axis1, axis2, JAX_WS, ...

My question is: **does Java, with some Java tool, have the capability of handling WCF message security with certificate?** If yes, which one and how?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. Really doubt if there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a solution. Although this type of communication may not be as easily used in Java as in .Net there is a way to achieve this with CXF and WS-Security.

There at least 2 approaches to do this. With [policy element embedded in wsdl](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html) file  or with [manually defined interceptors](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html). I will show here first approach but is shouldn't be hard to find the second one in mentioned docs.

1. Add appropriate tag ([Policy](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/v1.3/ws-securitypolicy.html)) in your wsdl file you need secured with https with message credentials. The one presented below will add a timestamp to your request and signed it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="uri://someservice.com/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
                  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="SomeService"
                  targetNamespace="uri://someservice.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:TransportToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Lax/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportBinding>
                <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
                <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Wss10>
                <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <sp:Header
                            Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                            Name="Timestamp"/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    ...
</wsdl:definitions>
```

2. Added dependencies to ws-security modules

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Generate stubs using maven [cxf-codegen-plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/SomeService.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/SomeService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

4. Create properties file with configuration of key you want to use. You have to specify there keystore used. In example this file is named `tls.propreties` and is placed under `/someservice/config/` directory.

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=/someservice/config/someservice.jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=qwe123
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=someservice
```

5. Create callback which will provide password to keys in your jks. Below I present the simplest possible implementation providing the same password for all key names.

```
private class KeystorePasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) {
        for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
            WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callback;
            pc.setPassword("password");
        }
    }
}
```

6. Enchance your port with properties telling it how to secure message. When using with spring I tend to wrap this enhanced port as a bean and later just inject it, so I don't have to configure it every time it is used.

```
@Bean
SomeService vehiclePricingGatewayService() {
    // this 2 below are classes genarated from our wsdl file
    SomeService_Service vpgService = new SomeService();
    SomeService port = vpgService.getBasicHttpBindingSomeService();

   Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();

    // add wssecurity keystore configuration properties
    try {
        requestContext.put("ws-security.signature.properties",
                Paths.get("/someservice/config/tls.properties").toUri().toURL());
        requestContext.put("ws-security.encryption.properties",
                Paths.get("/someservice/config/tls.properties").toUri().toURL());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("Error while reading tls properties", e);
    }

    // add alias of key from keystore which should be used
    requestContext.put("ws-security.signature.username", "someservice");
    requestContext.put("ws-security.encryption.username", "someservice");

    // we add callback whioch will provide password for used key
    requestContext.put("ws-security.callback-handler", new KeystorePasswordCallback());

    // additional properties
    requestContext.put("schema-validation-enabled", false);
    requestContext.put("set-jaxb-validation-event-handler", false);

    return port;
}
```

7. [OPTIONAL] If not using default Trustore you may want to set it with those jvm args

```
-Djavax.ssl.net.trustStore=/someservice/config/cacerts -Djavax.ssl.net.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

I suppose there may be more ways to configure such communication but It was the one I found, used and succeeded with.

Mind that this is only client configuration. If you would like to act like a server in this form of communication (you need to verify incoming signature) it is also easily configurable with wss4j interceptors which can be appliad to cxf soap enpoint as well as spring-ws endpoint.